# Has the function $F_s(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(k+1)^s}$ been studied before?

Tags: inequalities, special-functions

While studying an application of [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) I found that the function
$$
F_s(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(k+1)^s}
$$
for $s\geq0$ in some cases provides a sharper bound.
I had a quick look at the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) but couldn't find anything related.

It is clear that $F_1(x)=e^x$ and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it seems that
$F_n(x) = {}_{0}F_{n-1}(;1,\ldots,1;x)$
is a generalized hypergeometric function. However, I'm more interested in the case $s\in[0,1]$.

Is this function (and its properties) already known?

[image: Plot of F_s(x) for different values of s.]

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2

Comment: This is the partition function of the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson distribution, see for example https://www.stat.cmu.edu/tr/tr776/tr776.pdf (equation 6)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Thank you, that's a good keyword to look further. Of course also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution#The_normalizing_constant) has a section on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlo identified it as the normalization constant of the Conway-Maxwell-Poisson distribution (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%E2%80%93Maxwell%E2%80%93Poisson_distribution#The_normalizing_constant).

The first to study this function seems to be

- É. Le Roy: Valeurs asymptotiques de certaines séries procédant suivant les puissances entières et positives d’une variable réelle. (1900)

I also found some more references related to the generalization
$$ F_{\alpha,\beta}^{(\gamma)}(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)^\gamma}, \qquad z\in\mathbb{C}, \quad \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C} $$

- [S. Gerhold: Asymptotics for a variant of the Mittag–Leffler function. (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2011.596151)

  improves Le Roy's result to provide asymptotics for $F_{\alpha,\beta}^{(\gamma)}$
- [R. Garra, F. Polito: On some operators involving Hadamard derivatives. (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2012.756875)

  they call it the $\alpha$-Mittag-Leffler function and $\alpha L$-exponential function (for $\alpha=\beta=1$) and provide connections with the fractional calculus
- [R. Gorenflo, A. A. Kilbas, F. Mainardi, S. Rogosin: Mittag-Leffler functions, Related Topics and Applications. 2nd ed. (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-61550-8)

  see Chapter 5.3, they call it Le Roy type function